# Count number of values in json Angular 5

Tags: javascript

I have an array of same-type objects that looks like this:

```
let tasks = [
        {
          "name": "Moj Zadatak",
          "finished": true,
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "Moj Zadatak",
          "finished": true,
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "Novo",
          "finished": true,
          "id": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Prepravka",
          "finished": true,
          "id": 4
        },
        {
          "name": "Prepravka",
          "finished": true,
          "id": 5
        },
        {
          "name": "Najnovije",
          "finished": false,
          "id": 6
        },
        {
          "name": "Hajde",
          "finished": false,
          "id": 7
        },
        {
          "name": "Hajde",
          "finished": false,
          "id": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Novi Task",
          "finished": false,
          "id": 9
        }
];
```

I need to count how many are false finished, and how many are true finished values, to get like this:

```
let finishedValues = 5;
let unfinishedValues = 4;
```

Is there an easy and elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the array and then use length:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var obj = {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "Moj Zadatak",
      "finished": true,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Moj Zadatak",
      "finished": true,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Novo",
      "finished": true,
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Prepravka",
      "finished": true,
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Prepravka",
      "finished": true,
      "id": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "Najnovije",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "Hajde",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 7
    },
    {
      "name": "Hajde",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "Novi Task",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 9
    }
  ]
}


let finishedValues = obj.tasks.filter(n => n.finished).length;
let unfinishedValues = obj.tasks.filter(n => !n.finished).length;

console.log(finishedValues);
console.log(unfinishedValues);
```

Comment: I think applying `filter` 2 times is costlier than one time `forEach`

Comment: Another one we can use is, use `filter` once and subtract count of filtered values to total values length

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filer`

```js
var data = {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "Moj Zadatak",
      "finished": true,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Moj Zadatak",
      "finished": true,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Novo",
      "finished": true,
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Prepravka",
      "finished": true,
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Prepravka",
      "finished": true,
      "id": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "Najnovije",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "Hajde",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 7
    },
    {
      "name": "Hajde",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "Novi Task",
      "finished": false,
      "id": 9
    }
  ]
}

var counter_false = data.tasks.filter(el => el.finished ==false).length;
var counter_true = data.tasks.filter(el => el.finished ==true).length;

console.log(counter_false);
console.log(counter_true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `forEach` on your `tasks` array like this:

```
let finished = 0, unfinished = 0;
tasks.forEach(el => {
    if (el['finished'])
        finished ++;
    else
        unfinished ++;
});
```

Now you have these variables as you wanted.

```
finished equals 5
unfinished equals 4
```

And it is of course as half costly as `filter`, as you have to iterate twice in that method